# 'DIV' using remaining height doesn't work and includes footer

Tags: css, html

I'm having some problems with my design with regards to using the remaining height. I have an area with a background image, with underneath another div for text and some additional information.

But somehow the height settings for the 'text' area includes the footer area.

I have demonstrate the problem by setting a square background image in the text area. If it would resize properly the image would be shown as squared. But as you can see now in the JSFiddle example is that it includes the height of the footer as the image ratio is incorrect and considers the area covered by the footer as part of the text area.

How can i make sure the 'text' area is only using the available space between the footer and the centerphoto?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/v49c6/

and here is the style is use:

```
#container
{
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.column
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

#left
{
    width: 5%;
}

#center
{
    width: 90%;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

#right
{
    width: 5%;
}

#header
{           
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px; 
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: table-row;
}

#navigation
{
    float: right; 
    display: table-row;
}

#content
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

#centerphoto
{
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/') no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#centertext
{
    position: relative;
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: table-row;
}

#footer-line
{
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;

    border-top-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;

    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

#footer-photos-text
{

    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

and here is the HTML

```
        <div id="container">
          <div id="left" class="column">
          </div> 
         <div id="center" class="column">
            <div id="header">
                HEADER
            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                NAV
            </div>
            <div id="content">
              <div id="centerphoto">

              </div>
              <div id="centertext">
                  text - this is the problem area
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
              <div id="footer-line">
                <div id="footer-photos-text">
                  <div class="center">
                  Copyright
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
                       </div>
          <div id="right" class="column"> 
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what you wanted with doing the following things:

1. Change `#header`, `#navigation`, and `#content`'s `display` to `inline-block`.
2. Change `#footer`'s `display` to `block`.
3. Add:

   ```
   <script>
       var height = document.getElementById('center').offsetHeight-100;
       document.getElementById("content").style.height = height+"px";
       window.onresize=function(){
           var height = document.getElementById('center').offsetHeight-100;
           document.getElementById("content").style.height = height+"px";
       };
   </script>
   ```

to the end of you code.

Tell me if that worked for you.

Here is a jsfiddle to see the end result: http://jsfiddle.net/v49c6/1/